# Why does discord music not work on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I made a music feature for my discord.py bot and it all works fine when i run it from my machine but when i deploy it to heroku, the play command stops working.

**What I've tried:**

- Searching online for solutions
- Tweaking the code to see if i can figure out what's going wrong on heroku

**Expected Results:**
I expected the bot to download and then play the music using youtube-dl and ffmpeg

**Actual Results:**
For some reason it saves a certain file as a very long name that looks a bit like youtube-dl options.
This is the full traceback:

```
2020-09-19T09:59:56.637094+00:00 app[worker.1]: Downloading audio
2020-09-19T09:59:57.362517+00:00 app[worker.1]: ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'videoplayback-videoplaybackexpire=1600531195&ei=mtZlX7qyOcyfhwbXz42ICw&ip=3.80.84.128&id=o-ACr3otvjR8X3AKbcspCs4ohKJozzHs5FeSiCdpvKGRix&itag=248&aitags=133,134,135,136,137,160,242,243,244,247,248,278,394,395,396,397,398,399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=u9&mm=31,26&mn=sn-p5qlsndk,sn-vgqsrnel&ms=au,onr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=12&initcwndbps=886250&vprv=1&mime=video_webm&gir=yes&clen=22705009&dur=186.unknown_video.part'
2020-09-19T09:59:57.363053+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command play:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366683+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366721+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py", line 250, in download
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366722+00:00 app[worker.1]: ctx.tmpfilename, ctx.open_mode)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366724+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2054, in sanitize_open
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366724+00:00 app[worker.1]: stream = open(encodeFilename(filename), open_mode)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366762+00:00 app[worker.1]: OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'videoplayback-videoplaybackexpire=1600531195&ei=mtZlX7qyOcyfhwbXz42ICw&ip=3.80.84.128&id=o-ACr3otvjR8X3AKbcspCs4ohKJozzHs5FeSiCdpvKGRix&itag=248&aitags=133,134,135,136,137,160,242,243,244,247,248,278,394,395,396,397,398,399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=u9&mm=31,26&mn=sn-p5qlsndk,sn-vgqsrnel&ms=au,onr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=12&initcwndbps=886250&vprv=1&mime=video_webm&gir=yes&clen=22705009&dur=186.unknown_video.part'
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366779+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366779+00:00 app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366780+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366795+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366863+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366863+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366865+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/cogs/music.py", line 146, in play
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366866+00:00 app[worker.1]: ydl.download([url])
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366885+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2019, in download
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366886+00:00 app[worker.1]: url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366887+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366888+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366905+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 863, in process_ie_result
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366906+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366907+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1644, in process_video_result
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366908+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.process_info(new_info)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366923+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1926, in process_info
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366923+00:00 app[worker.1]: success = dl(filename, info_dict)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366925+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1865, in dl
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366925+00:00 app[worker.1]: return fd.download(name, info)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366941+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py", line 366, in download
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366941+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.real_download(filename, info_dict)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366943+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py", line 342, in real_download
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366943+00:00 app[worker.1]: return download()
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366959+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py", line 255, in download
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366959+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.report_error('unable to open for writing: %s' % str(err))
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366961+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py", line 165, in report_error
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366961+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.ydl.report_error(*args, **kargs)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366991+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366992+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.trouble(error_message, tb)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366992+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366992+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.366996+00:00 app[worker.1]: youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'videoplayback-videoplaybackexpire=1600531195&ei=mtZlX7qyOcyfhwbXz42ICw&ip=3.80.84.128&id=o-ACr3otvjR8X3AKbcspCs4ohKJozzHs5FeSiCdpvKGRix&itag=248&aitags=133,134,135,136,137,160,242,243,244,247,248,278,394,395,396,397,398,399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=u9&mm=31,26&mn=sn-p5qlsndk,sn-vgqsrnel&ms=au,onr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=12&initcwndbps=886250&vprv=1&mime=video_webm&gir=yes&clen=22705009&dur=186.unknown_video.part'
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367016+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367017+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367017+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367019+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367051+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367051+00:00 app[worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367053+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367053+00:00 app[worker.1]: await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367070+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367070+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2020-09-19T09:59:57.367092+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 36] File name too long: 'videoplayback-videoplaybackexpire=1600531195&ei=mtZlX7qyOcyfhwbXz42ICw&ip=3.80.84.128&id=o-ACr3otvjR8X3AKbcspCs4ohKJozzHs5FeSiCdpvKGRix&itag=248&aitags=133,134,135,136,137,160,242,243,244,247,248,278,394,395,396,397,398,399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=u9&mm=31,26&mn=sn-p5qlsndk,sn-vgqsrnel&ms=au,onr&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=12&initcwndbps=886250&vprv=1&mime=video_webm&gir=yes&clen=22705009&dur=186.unknown_video.part'
```

I got this through `heroku logs`.

**My code:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
from helpers.yt_searcher import search
from discord.utils import get
import shutil
import os


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.queues = {}
    
    @commands.command(aliases=['p'])
    async def play(self, ctx, *, search_query):
        url = search(search_query)
        
        def check_queue():
            Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")

            if Queue_infile is True:
                DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))

                length = len(os.listdir(DIR))

                still_q = length - 1

                try:
                    first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
                
                except:
                    print('No more queued songs.')
                    self.queues.clear()
                    return
                
                main_loc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

                song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)

                if length != 0:
                    print('Song finished, playing next in queue.')

                    print(f"Songs left in queue: {still_q}")

                    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")

                    if song_there:
                        os.remove("song.mp3")
                    
                    shutil.move(song_path, main_loc)

                    for file in os.listdir('./'):
                        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                
                    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)

                    voice.source.volume = 0.3

                else:
                    self.queues.clear()

                    return
                

            else:
                self.queues.clear()

                print('No songs left in queue.')
        
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")

        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3")
                self.queues.clear()

        except PermissionError as e:
            print("Trying to delete song file but it is being played.")

            await ctx.channel.send(':x: Error: music still playing.')

            return

        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir('./Queue')

        try:
            Queue_folder = "./Queue"

            if Queue_infile is True:
                print('Removed old queue folder.')

                shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
            
        except:
            print('No old queue folder.')
        

        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        ytdl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'quiet': True,\
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192'
            }],
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_opts) as ydl:
            print('Downloading audio')

            ydl.download([url])
        
        name = ""

        for file in os.listdir('./'):
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                name = file

                print(f"Renamed file {name}")

                os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
            
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=lambda e: check_queue())
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.3

        nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)

        await ctx.channel.send(f":musical_note: Playing {nname[0]}")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

This is all in a cog.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained. Please [edit] the traceback and relevant code _directly into your question_.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I preferred not to include the traceback and code into my question because they were extremely long! but if it would help get me to the solution, I'll edit the code into the question

Comment: I have just made the changes on the question!

Answer (score 0):

Get Help by watching this repo,  you have to install some build-packs on heroku as well like FFmpeg and Opus Library.

[Music Bot Repo](https://github.com/aamit2267/MusicBot)